# What can i do to print information from a nested dictionary that is send to class, and i need to show the result on the GUI

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am very stuck by trying to use tkinter, right now I am trying to print a receipt, my code works without the GUI, it prints the receipt sending the necessary information to a class, but now the professor wants us to have a GUI.

This is a one of the classes that I am using:

```
class Combo:

    def __init__(self, dish, drink, order, price):
        self.dish = dish
        self.drink = drink
        self.order = order
        self.price = price


    def combo_receipt(self, combo_number):
        """
        This is for printing on the receipt the information of the combo
        :return:
        """
        return f"Combo {combo_number}.\nDish {self.dish}.\nDrink Order {self.drink}.\nFood Order {self.order}.\n" \
               f"Price {self.price}.\n -------------"
```

This is how I am recollecting the information from a nested dictionary to send it to another function:

```
def receipt_print(customer_receipts, taxes):
    """
    This function will start the process of printing the receipt of the customer
    :param customer_receipts: receipts dictionary
    :param taxes: the tax to the math operation
    :return:
    """
    for key, value in customer_receipts.items():
        print(key)
    customer_name = input("Which receipt do you want to print?")
    if customer_name in customer_receipts:
        loop_print = int(customer_receipts[customer_name]["n_orders"])
        num_of_orders = 0
        total = 0
        for n in range(loop_print):
            if f"id{num_of_orders}" in customer_receipts[customer_name]:
                if "fries" in customer_receipts[customer_name][f"id{num_of_orders}"]:
                    fr = "fries"
                    order_type = "food"
                    id_num_of_orders = f"id{num_of_orders}"
                    cost = int(customer_receipts[customer_name][f"id{num_of_orders}"]["fries"]["price"])
                    total += cost
                    order_print(fr, customer_receipts, order_type, customer_name, id_num_of_orders)
                    num_of_orders += 1
                elif  "soda" in customer_receipts[customer_name][f"id{num_of_orders}"]:
                    sd = "soda"
                    order_type = "drink"
                    id_num_of_orders = f"id{num_of_orders}"
                    cost = int(customer_receipts[customer_name][f"id{num_of_orders}"][sd]["price"])
                    total += cost
                    order_print(sd, customer_receipts, order_type, customer_name, id_num_of_orders)
                    num_of_orders += 1
                elif "combo_1" in customer_receipts[customer_name][f"id{num_of_orders}"]:
                    cb1 = "combo_1"
                    combo_num = "1"
                    id_num_of_orders = f"id{num_of_orders}"
                    cost = int(customer_receipts[customer_name][f"id{num_of_orders}"][cb1]["price"])
                    total += cost
                    combo_print(cb1, customer_receipts, combo_num, customer_name, id_num_of_orders)
                    num_of_orders += 1
                elif "combo_2" in customer_receipts[customer_name][f"id{num_of_orders}"]:
                    cb2 = "combo_2"
                    combo_num = "2"
                    id_num_of_orders = f"id{num_of_orders}"
                    cost = int(customer_receipts[customer_name][f"id{num_of_orders}"][cb2]["price"])
                    total += cost
                    combo_print(cb2, customer_receipts, combo_num, customer_name, id_num_of_orders)
                    num_of_orders += 1
                elif "pizza" in customer_receipts[customer_name][f"id{num_of_orders}"]:
                    pz = "pizza"
                    id_num_of_orders = f"id{num_of_orders}"
                    cost = int(customer_receipts[customer_name][f"id{num_of_orders}"][pz]["price"])
                    total += cost
                    dish_print(pz, customer_receipts, customer_name, id_num_of_orders)
                    num_of_orders += 1
                else:
                    sp = "spaghetti"
                    id_num_of_orders = f"id{num_of_orders}"
                    cost = int(customer_receipts[customer_name][f"id{num_of_orders}"][sp]["price"])
                    total += cost
                    dish_print(sp, customer_receipts, customer_name, id_num_of_orders)
                    num_of_orders += 1
        total_print(total, taxes)
    else:
        print("Wrong receipt.\nBack to the menu")
```

In this case, the function that will handle the combos that the customer order, is:

```
def combo_print(combo, customer_receipts, comb_num, customer_name, id_or):
    """
     When this function is call, it will print the combo information
    :param combo: a variable to know which combo is in the order
    :param customer_receipts: receipts dictionary
    :param comb_num: a variable to be sent to the class Order
    :param customer_name: a variable with the name of the customer to read the receipt dictionary
    :param id_or: a variable with the name of the customer to read the receipt dictionary
    :return:
    """
    combo_order = customer_receipts[customer_name][id_or][combo]["order"]
    combo_price = customer_receipts[customer_name][id_or][combo]["price"]
    combo_drink = customer_receipts[customer_name][id_or][combo]["drink"]
    combo_dish = customer_receipts[customer_name][id_or][combo]["dish"]
    fill_object = Combo(combo_dish, combo_drink,combo_order, combo_price)
    print(fill_object.combo_receipt(comb_num))
```

And this will be calling the function `def combo_receipt` on the class `class Combo:`, so with this class and another three, one for Dishes, other one for Orders and the last one for the total, it will be printing the receipt for the customer.

This is what it prints:
[image: receipt]

Just for visualize, the nested directory looks like this:

```
receipts = {"jONH": {"n_orders": 1, 
                     "id0": {"combo_2": {"dish": "Spaghetti Carbonara",
                                         "drink": "Soda", 
                                         "order": "French Fries", 
                                         "price": "10", "id": "combo"}}},
            "Josh": {"n_orders": 2,
                     "id0": {"combo_1": {"dish": "Personal Pizza",
                                         "drink": "Soda",
                                         "order": "French Fries",
                                         "price": "8",
                                         "id": "combo"}},
                     "id1": {"soda": {"order": "Soda",
                                      "price": "2",
                                      "id": "order"}
                             }
                     }
            }
```

But as I already said, I need to use a GUI, but I know if there is a way to save the return value from the function `def combo_receipt` on the class `class Combo:` and send it to the GUI or what I can do to still be using the class and the GUI, cause it is requested.

I can't show you anything about my tries with this, cause I am really stuck with the GUI, so I am just watching video guides of tkinter or looking in google for information.

I will appreciate any advice, link or anything that help me to understand what I need to do

Comment: What are both filenames?

Answer (score 1):

I have here an oop solution for the GUI where you can implement your functions. In the main file you create the app, mainFrame and Notebook with a tab.
In the second File you get the class with the init function for Entries/Labels/Buttons, you have to add elements you need. On the bottom you are able to implement your functions. Hope that helps you further with the GUI.

main.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from abc import createUI0

# class MainFrame that inherits from ttk.Frame
class MainFrame(ttk.Frame): #ttk.Frame
    def __init__(self, container): #init method
        super().__init__(container)

        # Create notebook
        self.tabControl = ttk.Notebook(self)

        tab1 = createUI0(self.tabControl)

        # Create Tab from tab1 from file XYZ
        self.tabControl.add(tab1, text ='XYZ')
        self.tabControl.pack(expand = 1, fill ="both")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tk.Tk()
    app.title('XZY')
    app.geometry('670x580')
    app.resizable(0, 0)
    

    MainFrame(app).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    app.mainloop()
```

abc.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *


class createUI0(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container): #init method
        super().__init__(container)

        # field options
        options = {'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}

        # Titel Labels
        self.title = ttk.Label(self, text='XXX', font=('Helvetica', 17, 'bold'))
        self.title.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.W, **options)

        # Item Detail Labels
        self.itemDetail = ttk.Label(self, text='YYY:', font=('Helvetica', 16, 'bold'))
        self.itemDetail.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky=tk.W, **options)


        # XEntry, your variable to work with
        self.X = tk.StringVar()
        self.XEntry = ttk.Entry(self, width=23, textvariable=self.X)
        self.XEntry.grid(column=1, row=11, sticky=tk.W, **options)
        self.XEntry.focus()

        # Button to start your function for example
        self.button_create = ttk.Button(self, width = 15, text='use YourFunction', command=self.yourFunction)
        self.button_create.grid(column=0, row=22, **options, sticky=tk.W)

    def yourFunction(self):
        #your function
        pass
```